# Reading email messages using java mail api, get java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java, email

I am facing problem while reading messages using java mail api(jdk 1.6).
I am using part.getContent() method. and While getting the content of messages I am getting following exceptions.

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: X-iso885915
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: windows-1252http-equivContent-type
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: _iso-2022-jp$ESC
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: iso-8859-1
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: x-ias-norwegian
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: X-iso885915
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: cp-850
```

Is there any way to bypass these encoding exceptions.I need to read sender, receiver, received time of mail and attachment in the mail. I don't need to read body text. As there may be many more charset of such type. so how to read such type of encoded messages properly. I googled a lot but found no solution except a hint sun jdk may not support these char-set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that may be helpful. But i am not sure if this is right solution.

We can define a custom charset provider and let it know to jdk for example

```
package path.to.UnknownCharsetProvider;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.charset.spi.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UnknownCharsetProvider extends CharsetProvider {
private static final String badCharset = "_iso-2022-jp$ESC";
private static final String goodCharset = "iso-8859-1";

public Charset charsetForName(String charset) {
    if (charset.equalsIgnoreCase(badCharset))
        return Charset.forName(goodCharset);
    return null;
}

public Iterator<Charset> charsets() {
    return null;
 }
}
```

And to make JDK know about it, define a file named "**java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider**" in service folder in META-INF direcotry, and make entry of your charset provider in it for ex.
**path.to.UnknownCharsetProvider**
Than for a bad charset it will return the charset you want to return. However I am not sure if the charset provided by you for a bad charset can decode the message text properly or no not :(

From http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#imapserverbug for question  Q: Why do I get the UnsupportedEncodingException when I invoke getContent() on a bodypart that contains text data?